# $\gamma\mapsto \sup_{\xi \in \gamma}f(\xi)$ is not strictly bounded

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

This is motivated by Exercise 15(c) in Cori, Lascar, Pelletier.

Given a map $f:\beta\to \alpha$ whose image is not strictly bounded (i.e. the upper bounded of the image of $f$ is the ordinal $\alpha$). Let $\delta$ be the least ordinal in the set $\{\gamma\le \beta:\sup_{\xi\in \gamma} f(\xi) = \alpha\}$.

Define a map $g:\delta\to \alpha$ as:
$\gamma\mapsto \sup_{\xi \in \gamma}f(\xi)$

The solution manual then says the image of $g$ has no strict upper bound. I am intuitively convinced, but failed writing out a detailed proof. Any help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\delta$ is the least one such that $\sup f``\delta=\alpha$, we have that $g$ is a well-defined function.

Next, note that $g(\gamma)\geq f(\gamma)$ for all $\gamma<\delta$, that is an easy induction to write. And therefore, since $f\restriction\delta$ already is unbounded below $\alpha$, $g$ must be too.

Comment: Thanks! May I please ask what would go wrong with well-definedness if $\delta$ is not the least one? I do not see any risk in this definition.

Comment: Well, then if $\gamma<\delta$ is such that $\sup f``\gamma=\alpha$, then $g(\gamma)=\alpha$, so $g$ is not a function into $\alpha$ anymore...